# django admin filter_list by manytomany filed

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-3.2

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (???,)
```

How to filter the books of a particular author through the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can look "through" relations with double underscores, so you can filter on the `nickname` of the `author`s of that book with:

```
@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('authors__nickname',)
```

or as specified in [the documentation of **`list_filter`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter):

> (…)
>
> Field names in `list_filter` can also **span relations using the `__`
> lookup**, (…)

Comment: how can i set title for this filter, because in the side pannel filter just show <<By nickname>>

Comment: @originull4: you can make a `SimpleListFilter`, as is described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), where the `title` attribute determines the title.